# Return single value from a dataframe as a number

Tags: pandas, indexing, lookup

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["daily", "weekly", "monthly", "yearly", "daily_w"], data={'Multiple':[365, 52, 12, 1, 260]})
```

I want to feed it a variable and have it return the number:

choice = "daily"

I expect the result as a number 365

I have tried things like:

`s = df.loc[choice]` and then    `b = s.iloc[0,0]`, but this returns an unusable series

There must be a very easy one-liner to return a simple number?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need select by index and column `Multiple` use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with second argument column name:

```
s = df.loc[choice, 'Multiple']
print (s)
365
```

Comment: Thank you very much, For some reason it did not work in my jupyter notebook, gave the same 'series' error. However when I pasted it in a new Jupyter Notebook it worked.